# Checking existence of folders with/without spaces in names using IF statement in batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm checking the existence of 2 folders using **IF** statement but when I do it with quotations for the variable "%X%", I get no answer although it works for "%Y%". The only difference between the 2 folders is the space in the name. Does this space play a role in this error and why!?

Thanks in advance!

```
SET X="C:\New Folder"
SET Y="C:\New_Folder"

C:\Users\Administrator>IF EXIST %X% (ECHO 1) ELSE (ECHO 0)
0

C:\Users\Administrator>IF EXIST "%X%" (ECHO 1) ELSE (ECHO 0)


C:\Users\Administrator>IF EXIST %Y% (ECHO 1) ELSE (ECHO 0)
0

C:\Users\Administrator>IF EXIST "%Y%" (ECHO 1) ELSE (ECHO 0)
0
```

Comment: `set "X=C:\New Folder"` notice position of my first double quote.

Comment: whenever you have to handle strings with spaces, use quotes `if exist "%x%" echo yes`

Comment: @Stephan he is using double quotes, that is OP's problem, OP is also `set`ting his variable's path with double quotes and getting `""path""` and affectively testing `if exist ""C:\New Folder""`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `set` for directories with whitespace by adding the quotes to the path like:

```
SET X="C:\New Folder"
```

You are setting the variable to include the quotes. it will echo `"C:\New Folder"` when you type `echo %x%`

So by doing:

```
if exist "%X%" echo something
```

You are adding quotes, so you are checking existence of `""C:\New Folder""`

Instead set like this:

```
SET "X=C:\New Folder"
SET "Y=C:\New_Folder"
```

Now if you do:

```
if exist "%X%" (echo 1) else (echo 2)
```

it will echo 1.

Comment: Thanks Gerhard but if I do the following I will get no answer `if exist %X% (echo 1) else (echo 2)`

Comment: You cannot do that because you have a space in your path, then you have to add the double quotes. `if exist "%X%" ` You can add quotes for both paths with or without space, to keep a standard.

Comment: I mean is there a way to check it generally with/without quotation ? `if exist %X%` or `if exist "%X%"`. It would be helpful when the code is too long.

Comment: As it is about the existence of a directory, you should be using, `If Exist "%X%\" (Echo 1) Else Echo 2`.

Comment: no, you have to consider the limitations of a scripting language like batch. whether you add quotes in the wrong place when doing set, or if you add it in the `if exist` statement, you need those quotes. try this and see why. open cmd.exe and type `set "abc=This Line"` then do `echo %abc%` and see the result. then do `echo "%abc%"` and compare it with the previous result.

Comment: So simply stick to a standard of setting all your variables in this quoted order `set "a=some path"` and then do `if exist "%a%"` for everything.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Compo

Comment: Thanks a lot @GerhardBarnard

Comment: @Compo - What is the purpose of the REVERSE SOLIDUS (backslash) before the closing QUOTE MARK of the variable?

Comment: The backslash before the closing quote indicates that you are checking for the existence of a folder.  Without it, cmd assumes you are checking for a file.